# Number format with currency symbol

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to put a currency symbol before rounding off the values ? or Alternatives maybe .

```
echo number_format((float)$overall_total, 2, '.', ''); //748.10
```

Expected output should be : `$ 748.10`

Comment: what is your expected output then? $748.10?

Comment: echo '$'. number_format ...

Comment: @tim it did the job . thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$number = 1234.56;

// let's print the international format for the en_US locale
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
// USD 1,234.56
```

For more details: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 1):

From [tims's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862185/number-format-with-currency-symbol/56862669#comment100274120_56862185):

```
echo '$'.number_format
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '$'.number_format((float)$overall_total, 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use money_format()

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
```

For details please look [money-format.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)